# jquery expand div parent innerhtml height

Tags: jquery

Working prototype:
http://jsfiddle.net/ad5qa/K5fdZ/28/

For some reason when the more button is clicked the parentsUntil is grabbing all divs in the page. I just want to get the div.htmlbox and have the height auto so I can see the full contents. Then click less to shrink it back down to 50px height. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$('.morebox a').toggle(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var $parent =$this.parentsUntil('.htmlbox');

   $parent.height('auto')
   $this.text('less')
   $parent.css('border', '2px solid magenta')
   $this.css('border', '2px solid red')
}, function() {
   $parent.height('50px')
   $this.text('more')
});​

<h3>Description</h3>
<div class="htmlbox">
 This is a samle description that goes here with short or long content in this panel. If the text is higher than 50px then it should be hidden by the box. You must click expand to view the remaining content in the html box div. The float box is used to cut off the overflow of the content. 
<div class="fade-overlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="morebox">
    <img align="absmiddle" alt="more-less grabber" src="http://goo.gl/ho277">
    <a href="#" style="line-height: 10px">more</a>
    <img align="absmiddle" alt="more-less grabber" src="http://goo.gl/ho277">
</div>
```

Comment: Please always include the relevant code directly in your question.  If jsfiddle ceases to exist, the question should still remain useful to others.

Comment: According to your HTML, it doesn't seem that `.htmlbox` is a parent of the `.morebox`. As an example, `.htmlbox` is a parent of `fade-overlay`, but is on the same level as `.morebox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want that one element, then you wouldn't use `parentsUntil`, you would use `closest`.  **However**, `.htmlbox` is not an ancestor of your `a` at all.  You will need to do something more complex.  Additionally, you need to use `this` and not select all `a`s.

```
$this.closest(".morebox").prev();
```

Note that this is highly dependent on your current html.  If you change the structure you will need to modify this.

Answer (score 0):

Contain each paragraph + more button in a div then use the following code to select the more button:

http://jsfiddle.net/K5fdZ/44/

```
<div class="section">    
    <div class="htmlbox">
       MY_TEXT
       <div class="fade-overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="morebox">
       <img align="absmiddle" alt="more-less grabber" src="http://goo.gl/ho277">
       <a href="#" style="line-height: 10px">more</a>
       <img align="absmiddle" alt="more-less grabber" src="http://goo.gl/ho277">
    </div>
</div> 

var $parent = $('.morebox a').parent().find('.htmlbox');
```

Comment: Your code implies that `.htmlbox` is within `.morebox`.  It isn't.  You also are selecting every `.morebox a` and not just the one being acted upon.

Comment: With that html, you would want `$this.closest(".section").find(".htmlbox")`

Comment: Your edit did not fix it.  This is what it should be with that markup:  http://jsfiddle.net/K5fdZ/47/

Answer (score 0):

Consider wrapping each `.htmlbox` and `.morebox` inside a `div` and use jQuery $.closest() and $.find() to traverse the DOM like so:

**HTML**

```
<div class="boxcontent">
    <h3>Description</h3>
    <div class="htmlbox">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="morebox">
        ...
        <a href="#" style="line-height: 10px">more</a>
        ...
    </div>            
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.morebox a').toggle(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var $parent = $el.closest('.boxcontent').find('.htmlbox');

    $parent.height('50px')
    $el.text('more')
}, function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var $parent = $el.closest('.boxcontent').find('.htmlbox');

    $parent.height('auto');
    $el.text('less')
}).trigger('click');​
```

[Updated JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/K5fdZ/49/).

I hope this helps!